# Changing empty XML elements to elements with self-closing tags

Tags: xml, formatting

I have a few (~5) large (~1000 lines) XML files with many elements like this:

```
<Foo Bar="Baz">
</Foo >
```

I want them all to become like this:

```
<Foo Bar="Baz" />
```

Is there a tool or script that will do this for me automatically? Note: some elements aren't empty and shouldn't be changed to self-closing tags; there are only about 5 distinct element names I care about.

Comment: How large is "large"?  And do the "many" elements all have the same name or does it vary?

Comment: About 1,000-2,000 lines. Not enough to hassle a computer but enough to be too tedious to do it manually. There are only about 6 or so different names. Note that some elements with these names aren't empty and shouldn't be changed to self closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `xsltproc` or another XSLT processor then this should be quite straightforward. Now the example element you show in the question isn't actually empty because it contains a text node (the newline character). But XSLT allows you to specify elements within which whitespace-only text nodes can be ignored. Thus a style sheet like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="Foo Bar Baz"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should do what you need. The `strip-space` tells it which elements should have their whitespace-only text node children stripped, and the template is an identity transform that copies input to output unchanged (*after* the whitespace stripping, which happens at parse time). Once the elements really are empty the serializer should write them out as self-closed tags.

Comment: I don't think XSLT 1.0 specifies that the serializer MUST use self-closing tags, but it almost certainly will.

Comment: `xsltproc` definitely does use self-closing tags for empty elements, I've just tested this myself.